# Why does "The Last House on the Left" have that title?

Tags: title, the-last-house-on-the-left

In the original film [*The Last House on the Left* (1978)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068833/) and the [remake in 2009](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0844708) the house in question is a lake house in the woods with no other houses around. So what is the meaning behind the title *The Last House on the Left*? It sounds like it would be referring to a house on a street in a suburban neighborhood, so I don't quite understand how the title refers to the house in the movie. What was the reason Wes Craven chose this as the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They choose the name *The Last House on the Left* after going through different names even though it doesn't make sense.

May be they didn't get a good one in time.

> Wes Craven originally called the screenplay **Night of Vengeance**. Then it was **Sex Crime of the Century**, quoting a line of dialogue from the movie. Krug & Company, after the villains, was deemed not suitably ominous. Someone eventually came up with **The Last House on the Left**, which is ominous even though it doesn't make sense. (The house is isolated on a country lane with no other homes nearby.)
>
> <sub>[Reference](http://mentalfloss.com/article/87467/14-facts-about-last-house-left)</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Tha answer can be found on the original movie poster for the 1972 version o fthe film:

[image]

"She lived in the last house on the left".

Comment: I'm not following how this answers the question.

Comment: As the question and the existing answer point out, she *didn't* live on the last house on the left.

Comment: And IIRC, you had to take a left to get down the country lane.  Being that we really don't know what was beyond it, and considering the movie poster explicitly states "She lived in the last house on the left", how do we really know that she *didn't*, in fact, live in the last house on the left?  There seems to be more facts pointing to that being the case than there are contrary facts.

Comment: @JohnnyBones its mentioned in the movie that there isn't another house around for miles.

Comment: @sanpaco - **Exactly**.  It's the **last house on the left**.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Seems like a mistake between "Last house (that is) left" and "Last house on the left"